# How to bring in the login & reg forms into my wordpress theme?

Tags: php, wordpress, authentication, wordpress-theming, registration

I have been doing WordPress themes for a while, but the straight forward ones. Now this new client wants a theme that has the login and reg form in the theme with a lightbox. I have previously seen login forms included in themes so I agreed to that and told him that the reg form cannot be done. Then I saw **[modernman](http://www.modernman.com/)**. They've managed to bring in both the forms to the theme. Whether I tell that to the client or not, I'd still like to know how it's done.

Please help. I appreciate all the replies. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I always use the plugin [Theme My Login](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/theme-my-login/). It gives you fine-grained control over how/where the login/registration/password recovery forms appear and how they function, etc. Really, one of the better plugins out there.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answering, but I found out it works if I just hard code the form in my theme.

http://www.steelfrog.com/easy-user-registration-and-loginlogout-in-wordpress/